# Start the Week Number from the first sunday of every fiscal year in Excel

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to find the week number for a fiscal year which is starts on first sunday of February. I have got it to a point where I can get the week number which starts on first of every year (in my case feb).

Not able to start it from First Sunday. Below is what I've come up with.

```
=IF(AND(MONTH($E2)=2,DAY($E2)=1),1,ROUNDUP(($E2-DATE(YEAR($E2)-IF(MONTH($E2)<2,1,0),2,0)+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR($E2)-IF(MONTH($E2)<2,1,0),2,0)))/7,0))
```

I would also like it to end on Saturday of last week of the year. 
For example: in Feb 2016, the week count should start from 7thFeb2016 and the count should end on 4thFeb2017.

Comment: This appears to have nothing to do with SQL.

Comment: What is stored in cell E2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this formula to find week number of given date:

```
=IF(A1>=IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1),1)=1,DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1),DATE(YEAR(A1),2,7-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1),1)+2)),ROUNDUP((A1-IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1),1)=1,DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1),DATE(YEAR(A1),2,7-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1),1)+2))+1)/7,0),ROUNDUP((A1-IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1),1)=1,DATE(YEAR(A1)-1,2,1),DATE(YEAR(A1)-1,2,7-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1)-1,2,1),1)+2))+1)/7,0))
```

I hope you want this.

**UPDATED**

If you want week number of fiscal quarter, use this:

```
=ROUNDUP(MOD(=IF(A1>=IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1),1)=1,DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1),DATE(YEAR(A1),2,7-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1),1)+2)),ROUNDUP((A1-IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1),1)=1,DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1),DATE(YEAR(A1),2,7-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1),1)+2))+1)/7,0),ROUNDUP((A1-IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1),1)=1,DATE(YEAR(A1)-1,2,1),DATE(YEAR(A1)-1,2,7-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1)-1,2,1),1)+2))+1)/7,0)),13.01),0)
```

Comment: the first week of february is getting displayed as 0 and the weeks are incrementing hence forth.

Comment: Perfect! works like a charm! Now another task for me is I need to find a week of quarter. Concept is the same, fiscal year starts from Feb. please have a look if its not too much :)

Comment: The week number should restart first sunday of every quarter that is feb being the first fiscal quarter in my case..

Answer (score 0):

I just chucked this together (no doubt there is a more elegant way to do this). You can use it by putting it into a `Module` in your VBA editor and then on the worksheet use the function `=AltWeekNumber(E2)`

```
Function AltWeekNumber(endDate As Range) As Date
    Dim startDate As Date
    startDate = FirstFebruarySunday(year(endDate.Value))
    If startDate > endDate Then
        startDate = FirstFebruarySunday(year(endDate.Value) - 1)
    End If
    AltWeekNumber = DateDiff("w", startDate, endDate.Value, vbSunday)
End Function

Private Function FirstFebruarySunday(year As Integer) As Date
    For i = 1 To 7
        If Weekday(DateSerial(year, 2, i)) = 1 Then
            FirstFebruarySunday = DateSerial(year, 2, i)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: The first Sunday of a month can never be later than the 7th, so you simplify `FirstFebruarySunday` to `DateSerial(year, 2, 8 - Weekday(DateSerial(year, 2, 7)))`.