# Calculate the first week of year which starts from first Sunday of every Feb

Tags: excel, date, datetime, excel-formula, vba

I have an issue here. I want to calculate the week nummber of first sunday of business year. Where I work their calendar starts on February 1st. To calculate i have a column A2 in excel which has the date in mm/dd/yyyy format. I want to generate the corresponding fiscal week for the column.

example of my result set:

for 2/1/15 the week of year number should be 1
For 2/7/16 the week number of year should be 1

I tried the below formula, but its starting the week from the first day of the fiscal year and not the first sunday of the year.

```
=INT((A1-WEEKDAY(E9165)-DATE(YEAR(A1+7-WEEKDAY(A1))-(MONTH(A1)<2),2,1))/7)+2
```

Please help...

-Sandra

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Start the Week Number from the first sunday of every fiscal year in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40788022/start-the-week-number-from-the-first-sunday-of-every-fiscal-year-in-excel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your work years always start on the first sunday after February 1st:

```
=IF(WEEKNUM(A1)-WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1)-1)<=0,52+WEEKNUM(A1)-WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1)-1),WEEKNUM(A1)-WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1)-1))
```

We first determine the week number of the date starting from the first Sunday of February. To do this I have used `WEEKNUM()-WEEKNUM(02/01/SAMEYEAR)` taking 1 day from the date to force week 1 as Excel begins counting from week 0 by default. Using `IF()` we state that if the outcome is 0 or less then add the result to 52, which will give us the correct result for dates in January as they produce negative values.

**Edit - Very long formula but gives you the week of the quarter in Q1 W1 format:**

```
=SUBSTITUTE(CONCATENATE("Q",INT(IF(WEEKNUM(A1)-WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1)-1)<=0,52+WEEKNUM(A1)-WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1)-1),WEEKNUM(A1)-WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1)-1))/13)+(IF(INT(IF(WEEKNUM(A1)-WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1)-1)<=0,52+WEEKNUM(A1)-WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1)-1),WEEKNUM(A1)-WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1)-1))-INT((IF(WEEKNUM(A1)-WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1)-1)<=0,52+WEEKNUM(A1)-WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1)-1),WEEKNUM(A1)-WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1)-1))/13))*13)=0,0,1))," W",INT(IF(WEEKNUM(A1)-WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1)-1)<=0,52+WEEKNUM(A1)-WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1)-1),WEEKNUM(A1)-WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1)-1))-INT((IF(WEEKNUM(A1)-WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1)-1)<=0,52+WEEKNUM(A1)-WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1)-1),WEEKNUM(A1)-WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1)-1))/13))*13)),"W0","W1")
```

Apologies for the length, I tried multiple methods to try to find a neater solution, but this was all that I could get to work. It would be a lot neater if there were multiple columns used.

Comment: Perfect guys! just incase if i want to get the week split by quarter? how do i go about it? should divide tit by 4 quarters? but it won't be logical isn't it?

Comment: Do you have exact dates for each quarter? Or are they just first Sunday of each respective 3rd month?

Comment: @Sandra Updated for quarterly split, hope it's what you wanted, If this answers your question please mark this as an answer. Technically me and bzimor answered your inital query and this was an additional request. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula:

```
=IF(A1>=IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1),1)=1,DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1),DATE(YEAR(A1),2,7-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1),1)+2)),ROUNDUP((A1-IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1),1)=1,DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1),DATE(YEAR(A1),2,7-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1),1)+2))+1)/7,0),ROUNDUP((A1-IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1),2,1),1)=1,DATE(YEAR(A1)-1,2,1),DATE(YEAR(A1)-1,2,7-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1)-1,2,1),1)+2))+1)/7,0))
```

Comment: What's in `E2`?

Comment: Sorry worked it out, edited to A1 to reflect date value. Took me a while to follow the formula through, nice work around I like it. It does throw 53 for 1st Feb 2015 though for some reason (sorry to be a pain i like to learn from alternative methods)

Comment: @bzimor 2/1/15 monday should be week 1 but your formula is giving week number as 53

Answer (score 0):

Way late to the party but was looking for the answer and found this thread. Ended up play around with the function myself and it's much easier to just deduct the dates; =WEEKNUM("date"- days you wish to offset)

Ex; If cell A1 holds my date, 2/1/2021 I wish to convert; =WEEKNUM(A1-31) result "1".