# Excel Formula for Week Number with Week 1 Starting the First Full Week in April

Tags: excel

I have a work calendar that starts the first full week of April. I need a formula that gives me week number based on a date. Most formulas I have found address this problem use a single date as the first day of the calendar. Any idea how to do this?

Additional info: going forward I don't think it will matter if the week starts on Sunday or Monday if that makes it easier.

Thank you!

Comment: did you try the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40838016/calculate-the-first-week-of-year-which-starts-from-first-sunday-of-every-feb

Comment: Other than not allowing for week 53 that occasionally pops up it seems to be working.