# How to display each week range within a month always ending on Sunday

Tags: excel

I have a excel sheet I use for work in which I track each weeks invoices into a seperate tab for each week. I have a cell at the top of the sheets that displays the current month (cell F1) (any date of that month entered into this cell is acceptable, its formatted to display month and year only).

In a different cell (A5) I display that weeks date range (eg. Jan 1-7, 2024) for 1st week, then a second tab for week 2, 3, ect. Currently I am editing this date range manually, but I would like to learn to create a formula for this based on the month/year cell at the top.

The tricky part for me is a the first week will always start on the first day of the month and always end on a sunday, and the last week will always end on the last day of the month. Thus, the first and/or last week will not always be an equal amount of days.

Any help on how I could possibly accomplish this with a formula would be greatly appreciated!

[How it currently looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMX5T.png)

Comment: Many varieties on here, look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/40788022/4961700

Answer (score 0):

I can get you this far.

enter whatever value of date in cell B1 (i have 23 Feb 2024 and have formatted it to print Feb 2024)

in B3 `=DATE(YEAR(B1),MONTH(B1),1)` to find the first day of the month ( you can skip this if you enter 1st of Feb 2024 in B1

in B4 `=B3+8-WEEKDAY(B3,2)` and then drag this down at least 3 rows)

in E3 `=IF(B3+7-WEEKDAY(B3,2)<EOMONTH($B$3,0),B3+7-WEEKDAY(B3,2),EOMONTH(B3,0))` and drag this down at least 4 rows

in H1 `=TEXT(B3,"mmmm d")&" - "&TEXT(E3,"d, yyyy")` and drag it down at least 4 rows

now you can reference the H cells to your tabs

[image: end result with revealed formulas]